# This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed.

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed android studio and make emulator when run .I face a problem

cannot launch AVD in emulator
Output : emulatoe : Error x86 emulation currently requiers hardware acceleration
please ensure intel HAXM is properly installed and usable
CPU acceleration status : HAX kernel module is not installed
I search in google and stackoverflow and show many solutions after that the same error appear
when got to

C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

and install 
intelhaxm-android
the error :

This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed.

I have AMD processor and  WIN 7 Ultimate Hyper-V is off also the Hardware Virtualization is enabled.
 Can anybody help out

Answer (score 1):

VT-X and HAXM are Intel technologies. So no support in your case: AMD.

AMD has [AMD-V](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization) hardware assisted virtualization, but there's no AMD based Android emulator  images

Switch to Genymotion emulators. They are Virtual Box based and will run fast.

Comment: You forgot to mention that Genymotion doesn't have a free license.